# SceneSystem.LoadContent doesn't unload the previous scene even with LoadSceneMode.Single

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, scene

I'm creating an Hololens menu app. After various issues I'm now able to load the `menu` scene, click on a button to load a scene for example `cube` scene. My scene structure is the following one :

- loading : empty scene which loads the menu
- main : the menu scene, contains a menu with two buttons. `Button1` loads `cube` scene and `Button2` loads `circle` scene
- cube : a simple scene with a 3D cube
- circle : a simple scene with a 3D sphere

**The problem**
The problem is the fact that when I switch from `menu` to `cube` scene it doesn't unload the previous scene. So you can still see the menu in the cube scene. Here are my MRTK Scene System [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUExo.png) .

**What I've tried**
I have in total three scripts, the same as the [Microsoft sample](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenXR-Unity-MixedReality-Samples):
*LoadFirstScene* is the script contained in the `loading` scene which loads the menu and works :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadFirstScene : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static bool IsFirstLoad = true;
    private void Start()
    {
        if (IsFirstLoad)
        {
            IsFirstLoad = false;
            CoreServices.SceneSystem.LoadContent("main", LoadSceneMode.Single);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have *SceneLoader* which is where the bug is happening I belive. It's supposed to load the next scene and unload the current one since I use `LoadSceneMode.Single` :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneLoader : MonoBehaviour
{

    /// Request that the MRTK SceneSystem load a scene of a given name.
    public void LoadScene(string sceneName) => CoreServices.SceneSystem.LoadContent(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Single);
}
```

Finally I have `LoadingSceneUtilities` which is contained in `main` `cube` and `circle` scene in order to load the base scene (`loading`) :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;
using UnityEditor.Experimental.SceneManagement;
#endif

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class MainSceneUtilities : MonoBehaviour
{
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        void Start()
        {
            if (EditorApplication.isPlaying)
            {
                // In play mode, MRTK handles scene loading.
                return;
            }

            if (PrefabStageUtility.GetCurrentPrefabStage() != null)
            {
                // Do not additively load the base scene while editing a prefab.
                return;
            }

            UnityEngine.SceneManagement.Scene baseScene = EditorSceneManager.OpenScene("Assets/Scenes/loading.unity", OpenSceneMode.Additive);
            EditorSceneManager.SetActiveScene(baseScene);
        }
#endif
}
```

I don't understand why when I switch from `main` to `cube`, `main` is still loaded and displayed. It may be linked to the 3rd script, but since in the first one there is the boolean check it shouldn't be a problem.

I really took a look at the sample since it's working fine but I can't figure out why it isn't working on my own project.

Comment: _".xxx doesn't unload..."_ - Immediately I noticed your use of `static`.  Are you using it anywhere else other than on a value type?   When using `static` in Unity beware - [thar be dragons](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/DomainReloading.html).

Comment: what scene do you have loaded when you hit play?

Comment: @derHugo the `loading` scene which is an empty scene containing an empty object with the `LoadFirstScene` script

Comment: @MickyD I checked and the boolean value is true, I also tried with only `bool IsFirstLoad` and the issue remains the same

Comment: My point is that if you are storing any _objects_ like say a `Scene` into `static`, then that could be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically found my problem on this [Scene System documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/scene-system/scene-system-scene-types?view=mrtkunity-2022-05#content-scenes)

In MRTK Scene System settings I forgot to set the `Content Scene`. After adding the 3 scenes (`menu` `cube` `circle`) everything is working fine !

[MRTK settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kszfq.png)